# Is there a way to export kibana visualization data automatically for some time period?

Tags: elasticsearch, plugins, kibana

I want to get/export kibana enhanced data table's data automatically to a external file(.csv,excel...) or database like my sql. I know there is a way get data manually  but i want to do it automatically from some constant time period(like one day) frequently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Go to relevant vizualization**

1. Inspect -> view -> Requests -> Request
   and copy the request that create visualization and
   goto dev tool console and paste it.
2. Should add 
   GET [index pattern]/search
   above the request
3. Click the mark at right corner of dev console and click copy as cURl
4. Paste it to a script with frequet timeout(daily, weekly...) and get the output to a .json file